# Custom audio slider for React-Native

Tags: react-native, react-animated

I am trying to implement a slider for an audio player, the design is shown in the picture. Required functions: displaying the progress of the audio track and the ability to rewind beyond a certain invisible area "[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vJRT.jpg)

Comment: Please show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck.

Comment: There is only a slider in svg and that's it, the fact is that I don't even know which direction they are moving